# PBEWITHHMACSHA512AND256BITAES Throws org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException (Jasypt)

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt passwords using Jasypt. I have written the code as:

```
// Constructor
public Encrypt() {

    super();

    pooledPBEStringEncryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();

    pooledPBEStringEncryptor.setPassword(encryptionKey);
    pooledPBEStringEncryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHHMACSHA512AND256BITAES");
    pooledPBEStringEncryptor.setPoolSize(4);
    pooledPBEStringEncryptor.setSaltGenerator(new RandomSaltGenerator());
}
```

`encryptionKey` is a static String. And the code to encrypt is:

```
public static String encryptIt(String value) {

    String encrypted = null;

    // Encrypt & Encode
    try {

        encrypted = pooledPBEStringEncryptor.encrypt(value);            

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Security Error in doEncrypt: " + e);
    }

    return encrypted;
}
```

Now when I run the code. I get the error:

```
    org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:773)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.cloneAndInitializeEncryptor(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:535)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.cloneAndInitializeEncryptor(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:483)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:405)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.encrypt(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:456)
    at com.gtt.common.Encrypt.doEncrypt(Encrypt.java:96)
    at com.gtt.common.Encrypt.main(Encrypt.java:278)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:147)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:136)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:761)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot set up certs for trusted CAs
    at javax.crypto.b.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Jurisdiction policy files are not signed by trusted signers!
    at javax.crypto.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.b.c(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.b.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.b$a.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:734)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Security Error in doEncrypt: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.gtt.common.Encrypt.doEncrypt(Encrypt.java:101)
    at com.gtt.common.Encrypt.main(Encrypt.java:278)
```

Now initially I was getting the `EncryptionNotPossible` exception. But I googled a bit and I found that I needed to put the JCE jars (local and US policy) to my JRE's security folder. After doing that I get this error. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am using JDK1.8 if that is of any use.

Comment: Please post the complete version number of Java and Jasypt. Do you use any particular provider? Regarding your algorithm _PBEWITHHMACSHA512AND256BITAES_ I get a NoSuchAlgorithmException.

Comment: @Topaco My Jasypt version is `jasypt-1.9.3.jar` and Java version is: `java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.6.15 - pwa6480sr6fp15ifix-20200820_01(SR6 FP15+IJ26443))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 10 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20200729_452626 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 43296bc
OMR      - 08b0594
IBM      - 70917a2)
JCL - 20200720_01 based on Oracle jdk8u261-b13`. Its a IBM WebSphere JDK.

Comment: For me: `AlgorithmRegistry.getAllPBEAlgorithms()` returns `[PBEWITHHMACSHA1AND128BITAES, PBEWITHHMACSHA1AND256BITAES, PBEWITHHMACSHA224AND128BITAES, PBEWITHHMACSHA224AND256BITAES, PBEWITHHMACSHA256AND128BITAES, PBEWITHHMACSHA256AND256BITAES, PBEWITHHMACSHA384AND128BITAES, PBEWITHHMACSHA384AND256BITAES, PBEWITHHMACSHA512AND128BITAES, PBEWITHHMACSHA512AND256BITAES, PBEWITHMD2ANDDES, PBEWITHMD2ANDRC2, PBEWITHMD2ANDTRIPLEDES, PBEWITHMD5ANDDES, PBEWITHMD5ANDRC2, PBEWITHMD5ANDTRIPLEDES, PBEWITHSHA1ANDDES, PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2, PBEWITHSHA1ANDTRIPLEDES, PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2, PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC4,`

Comment: `PBEWITHSHAAND2KEYTRIPLEDES, PBEWITHSHAAND3KEYTRIPLEDES, PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC2, PBEWITHSHAAND40BITRC4]`

Comment: This is possibly an issue of your specific environment Java - WebSphere - Jasypt. [PBEWithHmacSHA512And256BitAES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/whats_new/security_changes_80/security_whatsnew.html#changes__strongalgos) seems to be offered by the IBMJCE provider (which is why it's not available in a standard Java environment). It's also possible that regarding the jurisdiction policy additional settings are required in the WebSphere env. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about WebSphere to help further.

Comment: Check also this [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/unable-install-sterling-b2b-integrator-error-javalangsecurityexception-jurisdiction-policy-files-are-not-signed-trusted-signers), the error messages are similar to those posted.